# Configure the OTLP address in spring boot 3

Tags: grafana, open-telemetry, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I want to congiure my OTLP addresses like described here

[image]

I added the following dependencies to export otlp data

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus'
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel'
    implementation 'io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-exporter-zipkin'
    implementation 'io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-exporter-otlp'
```

And configured them like so

```
management:
  zipkin:
    tracing:
      endpoint: http://grafana-k8s-monitoring-grafana-agent.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local:9411
  otlp:
    metrics:
      export:
        url: http://grafana-k8s-monitoring-grafana-agent.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local:4318
  tracing:
    sampling:
      probability: 1.0
```

But I get the following errors

```
Failed to export spans. The request could not be executed. Full error message: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:4318
 Failed to export spans
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://grafana-k8s-monitoring-grafana-agent.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local:9411": Failed to connect to grafana-k8s-monitoring-grafana-agent.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local/<IP-I-REMOVED>:9411
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Why do you use the zipkin exporter and set the zipkin endpoint if you only want to use OTLP? You should configure the OTLP metrics and tracing endpoints instead. Right now you configure the OTLP metrics endpoint and the zipkin endpoint without configuring the OTLP tracing endpoint.